# FP^NP-complete problems

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, propositional-logic

Is there any other standard FP^NP-complete problem other than the Traveling Salesman Problem? For instance, in the canonical propositional logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSP is actually OptP-complete and so are many other optimization problems, including [Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), [MAX-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem), 0-1 Integer Linear Programming. This class and proof technique is largely the work of Mark Krentel; [orig paper STC'86](https://books.google.com/books?id=68yDXzfRfBwC&pg=PA218). The [journal version of the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900396) has more details, including the fact that OptP is subclass of FP<sup>NP</sup>.

LEX-MIN-SAT, finding the lexicographically smallest satisfying assignment, is OptP-complete under metric reductions. There's also an analogue of [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem)
for LEX-MIN-SAT proved by Reith and Vollmer http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9809116.pdf

I think is almost a research-level, or at least graduate-level question, by the way.

Comment: Note that research level questions are fine on CS.SE as well.